# Multiplication of cell elements with a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

If I have a cell containing 2 matrices:

```
A = {[10  0  0 10  0 20 15;
       0 10 10 15  0  0 20;
      10  0  0 12 11  0  0;
      10  0  0  0 19  0 14;
      18 13  0  0  0 15  0;
       0 10  0  0  0 10 15] 
     [ 0  0 10  0 20 15;
      10 10 15  0  0 20;
       0  0 12 11  0  0;
       0  0  0 19  0 14;
      13  0  0  0 15  0;
      11  0 13  0 15  0]}

B = [500 550 600 650 700 550]
```

I want to *multiply each matrix with this vector in a way that 1st row of A is multiplied by 1st element of B, 2nd row of A with 2nd element of B, ..., and 6th row of A with 6th element of B*. how to define this since A is a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to operate on each element in `A` separately, and [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to multiply each row in the matrices in `A` by one element in `B`:

```
celltimes = @(A) bsxfun(@times,A,B.');
C = cellfun(celltimes,A,'UniformOutput',false)
```

the result:

```
>> celldisp(C)
C{1} =
  Columns 1 through 4
        5000           0           0        5000
           0        5500        5500        8250
        6000           0           0        7200
        6500           0           0           0
       12600        9100           0           0
           0        5500           0           0
  Columns 5 through 7
           0       10000        7500
           0           0       11000
        6600           0           0
       12350           0        9100
           0       10500           0
           0        5500        8250
C{2} =
  Columns 1 through 4
           0           0        5000           0
        5500        5500        8250           0
           0           0        7200        6600
           0           0           0       12350
        9100           0           0           0
        6050           0        7150           0
  Columns 5 through 6
       10000        7500
           0       11000
           0           0
           0        9100
       10500           0
        8250           0
```

---

As pointed by @Adriaan in the comments, in Matlab 2016b `bsxfun` is implicitly implemented, so you can just write:

```
C = cellfun(@(A) A.*B.',A,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: Do note that in R2016b implicit expansion has been implemented in MATLAB, making the use of `bsxfun` no longer needed. Might want to add that as a post-R2016b solution as well.